# Right way to use secret flag in docker buildkit

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I am struggling with the same problem mentioned by Gavin on
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865849/setting-docker-env-var-from-build-secret).

Specifically in with new
[docker build secret information](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information)

What is the right way to use it that feature?

Looking around on the internet I only found some variations of the same example in docker documentation mentioned above, which prints the secret on build time. Maybe I didn't fully understand the example, so please help me.

If there is no way to get the secret in build time an use in another part of a Dockerfile (e.g. an ARG variable or RUN command), when and how that new feature can be used to truly keep my secret safe and also do the work?

My go is to use this new feature in build time and also keep my secret information safe in case someone get my image file and execute a history on it.

For example, ff I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM influxdb:2.0
ENV DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
ENV DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
ENV DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD="mypassword"
```

How can I use that new feature mentioned in docker documentation to set my variable (DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD), for example, in a way that it will not logged in image history?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The documentation to which you've linked shows how to access the secret from a `RUN` command. Can you show us a *specific* example of what you want to do, and why you can't do it using the mechanism described in the docs?

Comment: Hi @larsks, I have edited the question, let me know if it is more clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I use that new feature mentioned in docker documentation to
> set my variable (DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD), for example, in a way
> that it will not logged in image history?

It depends on whether you need the secret only at build time, or
whether you actually want to use it at runtime. The latter situation
is probably more common, and there's already a canonical solution:

If you want to keep `DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD` out of your image
history, just don't set it during the build process. Require it to be
set a runtime, e.g., via the `-e VAR=VALUE` argument to `docker run`
(or the `--env-file` option):

```
docker run -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=mypassword myimage
```

You could have an `ENTRYPOINT` script that checks for the variable at
runtime and exits with a helpful error message if it's not set.

The official Docker images for things like MySQL and PostgreSQL work
this way.

---

In contrast, a build secret is meant for secrets that are only
required at build time.  For example, let's say your build process
needs to do something like this:

```
RUN curl -o /data/mydataset -u username:password \
  https://example.com/dataset
```

You'd like to share your `Dockerfile` and associated sources with
other people, but you don't want to share your username and password.
This is where build secrets come in.  You would instead stick your
authentication information in a file, and modify your `Dockerfile` to
read that information from a secret:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
  curl -o /data/mydataset -u $(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
  https://example.com/dataset
```

In this example, once we've copied the remote file into the image,
we're done with the secret: we don't need it in order to run a
container from the image; it was only required during the build
process.

NB: The above assumes that you're providing the secret at build time as described in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information), so your build command might look something like:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt -t myimage .
```

Comment: You are right.
Just one comment regarding **once we've copied the remote file into the image**.
Doing some tests here I noted that (like docker docs mention) the idea is to pass the secret file in docker build command (--secret flag).

Comment: Right, if you're using the `--mount=type=secret,...` command, you do need to provide the secret on the `docker build` command line. I'll edit the answer to make that explicit.