# How to mount secret file in docker image build & use variable from secret file in Dockerfile to authenticate a command?

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, docker-secrets

Can someone please provide an example of the following command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret:id=mysecret,src=/local/secret ...
```

I don't know how to access the variables from secret file after mounting.

For example: I want to set Proxy using the secret passed and run an install command

Answer (score 6):

Your secret would be mounted as `/run/secrets/mysecret` which can be accessed using the `cat` command. The `RUN` command might look something like below:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
    cat /run/secrets/mysecret
```

A more complete example below:

- Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=USERNAME \
    cat /run/secrets/USERNAME > /app/username.txt
```

- A docker image can be built from this file, with `--secret` flag using below command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=USERNAME,src=username.txt -t node:16-secret .
```

- Now the built docker image contains the contents of `username.txt` secret, which was passed at build time, as the file `/app/username.txt`. That can be verified using below command:

```
docker run --rm -it node:16-secret cat username.txt
```

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446874/right-way-to-use-secret-flag-in-docker-buildkit) for an example of using the mounted secret in a curl command

Answer (score -2):

You can use Docker's secret management feature to mount a secret file in a Docker image build and use a variable from the secret file in the Dockerfile to authenticate a command. Here are the steps to achieve this:

1. Create a secret file containing the variable you need to authenticate the command:

```
echo "mysecretvalue" | docker secret create my_secret_name -
```

2. Update your Dockerfile to use the secret:

```
FROM your_base_image

# Copy the secret file 
COPY --from=0 /run/secrets/my_secret_name /my_secret_file

# Use the secret value in a command
RUN my_command --auth $$(cat /my_secret_file)
```

Note that the `--from=0` option copies the secret file from the build context where the secret was added.

3. Build the Docker image with the secret:

```
docker build --secret my_secret_name .
```

This will build the Docker image with the secret file mounted and use the secret value in the command `my_command` using the `--auth` flag.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Every time I try to run a command with docker secrets, I get this error:
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.

I could init it, but I am scared it will change things and break my current installation.