# How/Where to save credentials to use from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I have a Dockerfile with the following content

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl gcompat


ENV REPO_USERNAME=username
ENV REPO_PASSWORD=password

# Create a directory for Puppeteer
RUN mkdir -p /puppeteer

RUN curl --user "$REPO_USERNAME:$REPO_PASSWORD" -o reqLoader-linux http://10.81.9.1/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux
RUN mv reqLoader-linux /puppeteer/reqLoader-linux
```

It works fine, as you see I use there username and password,
I want to save those credentials in a secure place and be able to access them from this script.

I am running this Dockerfile using .sh script in git bash(win 11)
This image will be created on the linux env in production and I want simple/minimal solution to achive this

I tryied to run `docker secret create my_secret ./credentials` and in the credentials.json I have

```
{
    "username" : "username",
    "password" : "password"
}
```

In this case, I get

```
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

should I init swarm and go that way?
another possible solution I am reading now is [compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#secrets)

the solution that I imagine should be an encrypted file in which stored the credentials and only docker can see it when running Dockerfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446874/right-way-to-use-secret-flag-in-docker-buildkit

Comment: almost, so the second part of the answer is very close, but it is unclear to me what I should hold in the mysecret.txt, key value pairs? in my case, the username password that I am using during the build time on my windows environment will be also used in the build process on the jenkins server when creating the image for production use

Comment: From the linked question, it looks like your mysecret file should contain just your username colon password. The $(cat... part will read that file and pass it as the -u (aka --user) curl parameter. Make sure add the mysecret.txt file to your .dockerignore and your .gitignore (if you are using git). You don't want that file baked into the container or commited to source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by doing the following steps

1. I created .netrc in the same level that my Dockerfile is
2. I added the following  content in the .netrc file `machine 10.81.9.1 login testusername password testpassword!`
3. I modified the .sh file to run the Dockerfile using this script `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=netrc,src=./.netrc -t $IMAGE:$TAG .` instead of the old `docker build . -t $IMAGE:$TAG`
4. modified the Dockerfile by adding in the first line `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental` and then to  download file using this command `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=netrc  curl --netrc-file /run/secrets/netrc --output reqLoaderLinux http://10.81.9.1/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux`

useful sources
[solution](https://kestel.medium.com/security-pass-secret-to-curl-command-in-docker-container-38e772073375) , about .netrc [file](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc)